# Transferring a domain to another registrar and downtime

Tags: domains

I have a domain A redirecting (301) to another domain B.

If I take the domain A to another registrar, what will happen with the site content? How much time will it be without showing the content?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you think the content will be affected.

When you change registrar they may (or may not) allow you include the DNS information. Most do now-a-days but that is not always the case.

However, the content on the server will not be affected by this move, the risk is when changing registrar is if they update the records (A records, MX records etc) and therefore point to your existing server. The key thing is when the switch between registrar's is complete, all settings are as they should be. This is what will create/not create downtime...

In regards to how much time, it depends on how quickly the transfer takes place, but if you speak to the new registrar and explain you want certain (all/some) records to be copied over too, they will do that for you. If not, you need to keep an eye on it, and as soon as the transfer is complete, log on  and update the DNS manually.

Answer (score 1):

First, nothing at all will happen to your site's content.

Most registrars take up to 24 hours to update/change your name server (to display your content on an another registrar. This means that the page/domain which is using 301 redirecting; which you are updating the DNS records to, will be down for a day at the most. It usually takes much less time than this, it will depend on how busy the administrators at the new registrar are at the time.

*Note: During this time, the domain where your 301 is directing to will be up and displaying your content, unless you are updating the name servers/records for the redirected domain's registrar as well. Also, some registrars with enough resources can have the DNS records updated within minutes, I have had this happen a few times.*

Answer (score 0):

There will be no down time the domain will be working similarly like it is working now.

Comment: Can you explain how this works with no down time more fully?

Answer (score 0):

Send the new registrar a support ticket and tell them that you need the DNS records transferred too. They got the work done and had no downtime.